# Background Color inside a cell is not changing in fpdf

Tags: php, css, fpdf

Im using fpdf to generate a pdf file for my reports and Im new to this.
I want to change the fill color inside a cell but whenever I reloaded the page, nothing
hapeens, It still the same white fill color. Here is my code :

```
<?php
   require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

   $pdf = new FPDF('P','pt','Letter');
   $pdf->SetFillColor(230,230,230);

   $pdf->SetTitle("Title Here");    
   $pdf -> AddPage();
   $pdf -> SetFont('Arial','',12); 

?>
```

What is wrong with my code? I followed the proper way of setting the fill color but nothing happens? Can anyone help me fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 22):

Tyr something like:

```
$pdf->setFillColor(230,230,230); 
$pdf->Cell(0,10,$text,0,1,'L',1); //your cell
```

Defines the color used for all filling operations (filled rectangles and cell backgrounds). It can be expressed in RGB components or gray scale. **The method can be called before the first page is created and the value is retained from page to page**.

Take a look to the [FPDF manual](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setfillcolor.htm)

Comment: Good answer @JuanSedano. It was helpful to understand that using a 1 is true and 0 is false option in Cell is how you can fill the background.  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Important to have the above statements in the same order, that is 1st setFillColor and then Cell params. Just wasted a few hours looking at code that was the other way around (Cell first and then setFillColor) and wasn't doing exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

```
mpdf->SetFillColor('RED');
```

Just set the seventh parameter equal to TRUE

```
$mpdf->WriteCell(38, 10, 'HELLO', 1, 0, 'C', TRUE);
```